# Operator == cannot be applied to Guid or int in Linq (MVC book example)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Working through the WROX "Beginning ASP.NET MVC 1.0" book I've hit a strange 'error'.

"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid' or 'int'". The line in questions is:

```
(p => p.ID_Officers == id).Single();
```

The full code is below, and Officers is my table, ID_Officers is my ID field. (I imagine that I could of used 'o' instead of 'p')

```
public ActionResult IndividualOfficer(int id)
    {
        OfficersDataContext dataContext = new OfficersDataContext();
        Officer officer = dataContext.Officers.Where
            (p => p.ID_Officers == id).Single();
        ViewData["OfficerName"] = officer.OfficerName;
        ViewData["Officer"] = officer;

        return View();
    }
```

Any words of wisdom for this beginner would be appreciated.

I might add, that although this book was recommended for beginners - boy it's dry. It's clearly laid out, obvious to see what needs to be added/typed in during the exercises, but I feel it's written for an experienced programmer coming over to MVC. Rather than a beginner programmer.

So, does anyone know of a more beginner friendly book (I like books and reading) that I could more easily sink my time and teeth into?

Thanks for your help and guidance.

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very simple.

`id` is an `int`.  `p.ID_Officers` is, as the error message states, a `Guid`, which is not an `int` and cannot be checked against an `int` for equality.  Two different types, you know.

I'm not sure where the `id` of the controller method comes from.  At some time you must present to the user a list of officers, and construct links that point to each individual officer which includes the `p.ID_Officers` in the definition of the link, but your route is expecting an `int`.  Without seeing how your routes are configured or your officer links are constructed, I can't give you much more of a hint than that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that `p.ID_Officers` is a `System.Guid` while the `id` you are comparing it to is of type `int`. So you can change the signature of your method to

```
public ActionResult IndividualOfficer(Guid id)
```

And now it should be able to compile.

Another option would be to change your id column in your database schema to an `int` instead of a `uniqueidentifier` (which becomes a `System.Guid` in .net).

Comment: That's assuming his routes and links are constructed correctly.  If not, the officer links may end up with a 404 or they may be shunted off to a different method.  Or, he may get lucky, of course.

Comment: I'll change my ID_Officer to an int. I tried uniqueidentifier because it seemed right...ah well. As for my routes - I haven't touched those yet so I imagine that are system defaults. 

I notice that I'm not allowed to simply change the Unique to an int. Are well, that's another thing I've learnt. I'm going to have to remove the database and then...