# Getting the current User in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I tried to get the current user Id through the User.Identity but in vain, i found [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924692/how-do-you-get-the-userid-of-a-user-object-in-asp-net-mvc)
that guided me to do the following : `Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;`
 
i went through the same mistake as in [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593774/mvc3-getting-an-id-from-another-table-when-i-have-the-membership-getuser-provi)! however the solution provided didn't work in my case. I have an accounts model as

```
 public class Account
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    ......
```

}

i want to link the billing information created to the currently logged in user 
so i tried doing the following as suggested

```
 if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
                billinginfo.User = db.AccountSet
                                   .Where(x => x.ID == userGuid).FirstOrDefault();  
            }
```

and i have the obvious error :

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Guid'
i couldn't get an answer from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280962/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-guid-or-int-in-linq-mvc-book-example)
i tried to convert the Guid to int but that generated a wrong id since the conversion is utmost to 64 bits

So i want to get the currently logged in user and be able to access all his attributes

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you change `int ID` to `GUID ID` type?

Comment: i am trying that, but i had to manually create a new guid for each uses, moreover (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey returns a new guid >>currently checking that 
also the EF code first convention is to have the ID int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare integer with a GUID. It doesn't make sense. In order to relate the 2 tables you will have to use the same datatype column in both of them.

Comment: finally found the solution >> was rather simple
i linked them using the user name available in the Microsoft membership as follows 
`
     if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    String currentUser = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
                    billinginfo.User = db.AccountSet
                                       .Where(x => x.UserName
                                       .Equals( currentUser )).FirstOrDefault();
                    
                }`
Thanks for help and comments :)